# Can't click on hidden div (Bootstrap)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have "dropdown menu" where list items implemented via divs. How I can click on div which presents but is not visible?
Have a next method:

```
def select_author(author)
  self.div_element(:xpath => "//div[text()='some member']").click
end
```

But I getting an error that cannot click on element.

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Cannot click on element
```

And if I use selenium webdriver or Selenium IDE (for experiment):

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[text()='some member']").click
```

everything is ok.

[image: Code example]

Comment: Do you need to perform some action to make the element visible? Maybe try using a wait - eg `self.div_element(:xpath => "//div[text()='some member']").when_present.click`

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it also but, element exists and becomes visible if I scroll down to it . But I can't scroll down this customized list using watir.

Comment: What is the funniest thing, Selenium IDE does it very simple using xpath: `click | //div[text()='Member Automation']`

Comment: It would help if you could extract enough HTML and CSS for us to be able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, I think we should follow to private chat.

Comment: How can I connect with you?

Answer (score -1):

try to find this way, its capybara code but you will get the idea to find hidden elements

```
page.should have_css('#sample', visible: false, text: 'some member')
```